# iOS - dependent constraints console output with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am making an iOS app that uses popovers on several occasions.  I get the following output message to the console every time one specific popover is dismissed (but not when any of the other popovers are dismissed):

> All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and also from the view's list of dependent constraints

I have searched Google and this site for that phrase and nothing has come up.  I am not sure why it would happen for only one popover and not others.  Would it have something to do with its view controller?  The popover itself?  I am an autolayout novice, so there may be something simple I'm missing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue i solved it by removing the Use AutoLayout checkbox from the XIB, the auto layout XIB is present in the file inspector option.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: But what if we're using auto-layout on purpose?